# Configure GNOME/Wayland display configuration from command line

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, display-settings, wayland

Is there a possibility to configure the monitor configuration of Mutter/GNOME shell from command line in a Wayland Session or is that not implemented until now?

I have tried to change some things via the xrandr command (but it seems obvious to me, that this can not work as the "x" in xrandr indictates that it is a tool for the XServer).

This command has no effect (using Fedora 23 / GNOME 3.18.2)

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --off
```

However the included gnome settings dialog for the display configuration is working. A hint to a configuration file or a command line tool would be nice...

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/Gaps/DisplayConfig

Comment: Could KMS or DRM be used for this? I've been searching but have yet to find any solution. I also need to be able to toggle a display without going trough the settings.

Comment: I think in the end i came up with a hacky solution through a dbus command line client... The link don_chrissi posted provided some hints about that. Maybe there is by now also a command line version available...

Comment: Could you share your solution?

Comment: it looks like I can access that interface through `dbus-send`. For example I can call `GetResources`: `dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig --type=method_call --print-reply /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetResources`. Still trying to figure out how to edit the configuration...

Comment: Consider using [this](https://gitlab.com/Oschowa/gnome-randr) python script.

Answer (score 8):

The Mutter docs specify the interface with dbus as @don_crissti has pointed out in comments:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/blob/master/src/org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.xml

You need to find out your configuration serial and your connector:

configuration serial is the first number shown in

```bsh
gdbus call \
--session \
--dest=org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig \
--object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig \
--method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.GetResources
```

in my case that is `uint32 3`, so I use 3

connector: it shows in `ls /sys/class/drm`, in my case by trial and error I found that `card0-DP-2` was the correct one so I use `DP-2`. You can also try to make sense of the output of `DisplayConfig.GetResources` and use that.

By setting the other options, the final command becomes like this:

```bsh
gdbus call \
--session \
--dest=org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig \
--object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig \
--method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.ApplyMonitorsConfig \
3 1 "[(0, 0, 1, 0, true, [('eDP-1', '1920x1080@60.0', [] )] )]" "[]"
```

Unfortunately, that does not work for me, even though I am passing the resolution (aka. "mode id") in the right format:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Invalid mode '1920x1080@60.0' specified
(According to introspection data, you need to pass 'uua(iiduba(ssa{sv}))a{sv}')
```

EDIT:

I found why, the refresh rate needs to be THE EXACT STRING that `DisplayConfig.GetResources` is reporting. It does not let you set what you want as refresh rate sadly! So you have to use some arbitrary string like `59.810825347900391` like so:

```bsh
gdbus call \
--session \
--dest=org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig \
--object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig \
--method org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.ApplyMonitorsConfig \
3 1 "[(0, 0, 1, 0, true, [('eDP-1', '1920x1080@59.810825347900391', [] )] )]" "[]"
```

In conclusion, this is of very limited use. There should be a way of adding display modes, by generating CVT or GTF timings, but it looks like DisplayConfig does not have an interface for that :(