# How to turn off specific display on command line with wayland

Tags: linux, xrandr, wayland

Previously I used a linux system which didn't use Wayland and I was able to control my displays through the xrandr program. So to turn off my third display I used this command:

```
$ xrandr --output DP-1 --off
```

But now with Wayland this no longer works even if I use the new display names:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
   1920x1200     59.88*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+0+120 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 210mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
XWAYLAND2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.96 +

$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND2 --off
<nothing happens>
```

So is there a way to turn displays on and off on the command line when Wayland is used? I know I can control this in the gnome settings but I need to do it on the command line. So if there is some gsettings command to achieve this then this is also fine.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275327.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `wlr-randr` to achieve this (https://github.com/emersion/wlr-randr).

List your displays/devices with one of those two commands:

`$ ls /sys/class/drm`

or

`$ wlr-randr`

And then run (where DP-1 is the name of the device/display) to turn it off:

`$ wlr-randr --output DP-1 --off`

(There's also a GUI friendly version like `arandr` which is named `wdisplays` https://github.com/cyclopsian/wdisplays)

Comment: Extra info, for `sway` (swaywm) users you don't need to install `wlr-randr`, you can use `swaymsg` instead:

`$ swaymsg -t get_outputs | grep 'name'`
`$ swaymsg output DP-1 disable`

Comment: "compositor doesn't support wlr-output-management-unstable-v1". Bah. Which compositors do that?

Comment: wdisplays seems dead.