# turn off display via CLI in RHEL 8

Tags: rhel, display, wayland

Have a laptop running RHEL 8.4 without the gui. I would like to power off the display.
I use to run `vbetool dpms off` on ubuntu but that doesn't work,

```
user@server# ls /sys/class/drm
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-LVDS-1  card0-VGA-1  renderD128  version
```

**[Update]** I'm not using Wayland or X11, session type is shown as tty.

```
user@server$ loginctl show-session "$XDG_SESSION_ID" -p Type
Type=tty
```

**[Update]**
These commands complete successfully but have no affect

```
user@server$ setterm --blank force 
user@server$ setterm --powerdown 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off specific display on command line with wayland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495063/how-to-turn-off-specific-display-on-command-line-with-wayland)

Comment: This didn't work for me I couldn't get it installed correctly.

Comment: After running this command it shows im not using wayland or x11 instead it's tty `loginctl show-session "$XDG_SESSION_ID" -p Type`
`Type=tty`

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_Power_Management_Signaling#DPMS_interaction_in_a_Linux_console_with_setterm

Comment: These commands complete successfully but have no affect `setterm --blank force` and `setterm --powerdown 1`

Comment: You need to wait a minute :-)