# Horizontal flipping of display with Wayland

Tags: display, wayland, mutter

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 with Wayland. I use 3 extended displays, one being a small screen to be projected on a teleprompter.

Is there a way to horizontally mirror/flip a display such that looking at it in a mirror it looks oriented correctly?

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538054) led me to [the Mutter DBus configuration](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/blob/main/data/dbus-interfaces/org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig.xml#L379) which indicates that this type of transformation seems possible but I can't figure out the incantation that would allow me to use it.

Comment: Look at `wlr-randr` and `gnome-randr`.

Comment: `gnome-randr` is a neat project but unfortunately, it doesn't support horizontal mirroring. `wlr-randr` is for `wlroots`