# My Lenovo Ideapad gaming 3 refresh rate can not be set to 60hz from 120z

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, display, xrandr, wayland

I recently installed ubuntu in my Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 and I wanted to set the refresh rate to 60hz so that I can save more battery.

The option for changing the refresh rate is not offered (nor was it under Windows 11 either).

- I tried using `xrandr` to set the refresh rate but its not changing. `xrandr` is only showing 120 Hz as refresh rate.
- `nvidia-settings` in Linux is also not showing anything.

If any one know how to change this kindly help[image]

I have tried doing mentioned in [this link](https://davejansen.com/add-custom-resolution-and-refresh-rate-when-using-wayland-gnome/) and updated the grub in
`/etc/default/grub` and tried updating the grub but the grub file was not updated and display was still locked at 120 Hz. Don't know whether I am updating grub in the wrong way - I used a gedit to update it and saved it and used `sudo update-grub` in command line.

Comment: you're using xrandr on Wayland. Won't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure GNOME/Wayland display configuration from command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275327/configure-gnome-wayland-display-configuration-from-command-line)

Comment: So how to change the refresh rate on wayland then

Comment: No still not able to configure

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you've tried.

Comment: have added that in the details right now. Thanks for helping out